# Set up yii2 basic application on server

Tags: php, configuration, yii2

I have a yii2 basic template working fine in local, but when I uploaded files on server it is not working.

**index.php**

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
//defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
//defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

when I open URL `http://iicose.com/mlm/web/index.php` it gave me following error

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/iicose/public_html/mlm/index.php on line 12

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/iicose/public_html/mlm/index.php on line 12
```

I figured out that it is causing because of using `__DIR__` when I removed this the file loaded. But further I have to change everywhere in the vendor directory according to it which I think is not a good practice.

Can someone tell me a fix to this.

**EDIT:**
This question is duplicate of 
[Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156251/unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-92-state-1)

Comment: What's the PHP version on production server? Seems like it's older version without namescaces support. Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156251/unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-92-state-1

Comment: @arogachev Great help. I have PHP version >5.3.0 thats why its happening. If there is a way to solve this issue without changing PHP version (if possible).

Comment: Did you mean lower than `5.3.0` on production server? Yii 2 requires PHP 5.4, so you must have at least this version on both development and production servers to get it working.

Comment: Glad to help, I issued that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using older version of PHP (without namescaces support) on production server. Check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156251/unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-92-state-1).

Yii 2 [requires](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-yii.html#requirements-and-prerequisites) at least **PHP 5.4**, so you must have at least this version on both development and production servers to get it working.