# Two Errors whilst installing phpBB onto my forums

Tags: php, phpbb, forums

So auto installer was down on my web host provider and this was the first time trying to install a forums. I do not understand coding so when i cam across these errors i wasn't sure how to fix them.
Here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I downloaded it straight from the phpBB website unedited.

Code:

```
{
            $json_response = new \phpbb\json_response();
            $json_response->send(array(
                'success'   => true,
            ));
        }
```

Comment: You should copy and paste the actual errors and code here.

Comment: Seems to be dependent on your version of PHP... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156251/unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-92-state-1

Comment: so from what i read i need to update my php version as its 5.2? But i can't do that as my web host isn't that accessible, what should i do? download a lower phpbb version to suit php 5.2?

Comment: Sorry, I can't advise on that. I'd talk to your hosting company about updating or phpbb about a version compatible with 5.2..