# Laravel error after upload

Tags: laravel, upload, server

I have errors after i upload my project

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /wwwroot/public/index.php on line 53
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /wwwroot/public/index.php on line 53

```
$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156251/unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-92-state-1

Comment: What version of php is your server running?  It might not support namespaces.